# To find perpendicular of right angled triangle

Tags: triangles

If given slope of  hypotenuse and length of base, how can we find length of perpendicular ?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple Cartesian terms, "slope" is how much the $y$ coordinate changes with respect to the $x$ coordinate. For linear functions, it is defined as $\Delta y /\Delta x$:

[image: Slope]

$slope = \Delta y /\Delta x = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$.

Rearranging the above equation, you get:

$$\Delta y = slope \cdot \Delta x$$

Which would allow you to solve your question.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

the slope is basically the ratio of height and base, right? So it's slope=perpendicular/base and rearrange that

Comment: why is slope ratio of height and base

Comment: that's sort of its definition-for instance the slope of a line in xy coordinate is the change in y over the change in x. In case you don't understand you might wanna google pictures of a slope and see some examples.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.